# C++ getter for vector type class member

Tags: c++, oop

If I have `vector` or another object as a class property, then how should I implement a getter for that property? Should it return the member itself or reference of it? Example below:

```
#include "B.h"
#include <vector>

class A {
    vector<int> numbers;
    B obj1;

public:
    vector<int> get_numbers() const;
    // or
    vector<int> & get_numbers() const;

    B get_obj() const;
    // or
    B & get_obj() const;
};
```

Note: Also I am not sure about the `const`.

Comment: One school of thought says you don't need a getter at all.

Comment: Depends on how you want your getter to work. Do you want people to be able to modify `number` or `obj1` by using the getter?

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm, I didn't think it that way. Can they do it? They are private.

Comment: @Shadovx If you return by reference, then you are allowing someone to capture that reference and be able to modify the object held in the class.  Doesn't mater that it is private.

Comment: @Shadovx If the getter returns a reference to a private member, then callers can modify the member. `private` is only used by the compiler when processing code to enforce design habits, it has no real effect at runtime.

Comment: @NathanOliver Then it is clear that I should not return it by reference.

Comment: @Shadovx you could return it by `const` reference, that would prevent the caller from modifying the member, without making a copy of the member

Comment: Usually you'd want to return a `const vector<int> &` from a getter

Comment: @Shadovx Then your only option if you want to *guarantee* no modification is to return by value.

Comment: So I am a bit confused. It is different than the `const` which is at the end of the function declaration, right? I mean `B & get_obj() const`. It is not that right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not really.  It would be perfectly legal to cast away the const since the underlying object isn't const.  I will agree though that any code not interfacing with an old school API should not pass code review using `const_cast`.

Comment: @Shadovx the `const` at the end of the function means the function does not modify the `A` object it is called on, and thus is safe to call on a `const A` object. That `const` has no effect on what the function returns. You would need a separate `const` for that, eg: `const B & get_obj() const`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> vector<int> & get_numbers() const;
> ```

Definitely **not** this. You'll find it difficult to return a reference to non-const referring to a member from a const qualified member function.

> ```
> vector<int> get_numbers() const;
> ```

This is an option. But there are considerations:

- There is no way to modify the member using this approach. This is good unless you need to modify them.
- This requires you to copy the vector on every call to the getter. That can be potentially very expensive operation.

To avoid unnecessary copying, you can return a reference to const instead:

```
const vector<int> & get_numbers() const;
```

To avoid even more unnecessary copying by allowing move construction from the getter, you can use a set of overloads:

```
const vector<int> &  get_numbers() const & ;
      vector<int> && get_numbers()       &&;
```

To allow modification, you can use a non-const qualified member function returning a reference:

```
      vector<int> &  get_numbers()       & ;
```

---

Another approach is to not use a getter at all. If the user of the class needs access to the member, then perhaps it should be public.

You could instead provide other forms of limited access. An Idiomatic C++ way would be to have `begin` and `end` member functions that return iterators. This would allow changing the content of the vector without allowing resizing it.

Comment: `const vector<int> && get_numbers() const &&;` That's a crazy overload.  Not going to be able to get much use out of that.

Comment: @NathanOliver whoops. forgot to remove const. But that is something that's acutally used. I'm not able to describe the exact case why and where it would be useful though. Probably something to do with templates.

Comment: I get having `vector<int> && get_numbers() &&;` but `const vector<int> && get_numbers() &&;` really isn't useful since you can't move something that is `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/bk8j8v/uses_of_const_t/emeu810?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)'s a list of usages of `const &&` in the standard library API. In particular, `std::optional` uses it in a member function qualifier. (Edit: fixed the other const && as well)